# How to extract Google contacts pictures?

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

I would like to have all my Google contacts' pictures extracted in a folder, for instance in JPG format.

I know that it's already possible to export all contacts including pictures, for instance via the *Export* option in Google Contacts or via a third-party app such as [Contacts Backup Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.specsoft.contactsbackupultimate). However, this generates a bundle of all contacts (for instance, a VCF file generated via the *Export* command above will contain all pictures Base64-encoded). I would like to obtain instead a image file for every contact so that they are easily viewable.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract Google contacts you can use the web application provided by Google for free: [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com). This application helps to extract all the data stored in Google Apps including contacts saved on Google. All you need to do is sign in with the Gmail id where all the contacts are saved, and then choose the contacts section to extract the files. Later, you will receive an email that will be containing all the information of contacts in a vCard file.

Comment: This did not export all images for some reason.

Answer (score 9):

For Android device follow below steps :

1. Go to Chrome & visit https://contacts.google.com
2. Select the contact whose photo you want.
3. Tap on option, select export & select Google CSV.
4. Then the file will be downloaded.
5. Open that file in excel sheet (WPS office or MS office Android app).
6. Go to column name photo & select and copy the URL.
7. Paste it on Chrome's address/search bar & hit enter.
8. The image is opened just press & hold on image and save/download it.

I think this will be helpful to you.

Comment: It sounds even more complicated than @Charlie's answer below.

Comment: I see a column (AB) called photo, but there isn't any text/url under it. Tried on desktop and phone.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Contacts on the web, click on contact then right click on photo. Select "inspect",
The code for retrieving your photo will be highlighted in a popup window. Click on that URL and then do a screen capture and edit the photo.

Comment: Thanks, but even if I wanted to do this manually (which I don't) there is probably a better way.

Answer (score -1):

Open the contact. Under the contact name, scroll down for Google Profile. If you right click on the photo, you have the option to save or download the image.